# Call to External function is not working from stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Invoking the external function using the select query below works, but when the same function is called using `call_udf` or invoked using a select inside a `session.sql` doesn't make a call to the external function.

This works:

```
select djone_src.sf_notify.lambda_sns_notify('subject','body','ebs-international-trigger-timely') 
from dual;
```

But the same external function called from the procedure below is not working:

```
USE DATABASE DJONE_DEV;
create or replace procedure email_last_results(subject string, sns_topic string)
returns string
language python
runtime_version=3.8
packages = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'tabulate')
handler = 'x'
execute as caller
as
$$
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import call_udf


def x(session, subject, sns_topic):
     try: 
        body = session.sql(
         "select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1))) limit 100"
                    ).to_pandas().to_markdown()
     except snowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSQLException as e:
        body = '%s\n%s' % (type(e), e)
     
     call_udf(
      'djone_src.sf_notify.lambda_sns_notify','subject','body','sns_topic')
     return 'email sent:\n%s' % body
$$;

call email_last_results('para@email.com', 'results from snowflake', 'ebs-international-trigger-timely');
```

I have tried running using `call_udf` and trying to invoke with a select query, but neither of them seems to make the call.  The query profile does not show any details. Is there a session log level that may help to provide more visibility to what is occurring?

Comment: A function returns a value but you don’t seem to be returning the value to anything. Shouldn’t the syntax be something like: var_name = call_udf(…

Comment: The function actually makes a call to an SNS topic in AWS, so it usually sends out an email.

Comment: I’m not sure how your comment relates to mine - as I was talking about what a function returns, not what it might execute? A function, as opposed to a procedure, has to return a value so you have to use it in a context where a value is expected. Consider how you use UDFs normally - they have to be part of a SQL statement, you can’t “call” a UDF in the same way that you can call an SP

Comment: Calling external functions via `call_udf` cannot work since the return type of call_udf is of `Column` type as you can read [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.call_udf) which is actually a column or an expression in a Dataframe, as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Column#snowflake.snowpark.Column)